Cannot able to align in the text widget inside the row
class homeproductcard extends StatelessWidget {
  homeproductcard({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Image.network(
              height: 150,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/christmas5402acaad884&w=996',
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                "SAD",
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Text(
            "pro",
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Iam trying to align the (SAD text) from the Margin . So , I am Wrapping that with row and made mainaxis alignment = Mainalignment.start , but its not working

Please share image you want to create.

Your question isn't clear about what to achieve. Please share some design images or at least add a detailed description.

Move your Text("pro") in Row as below
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(
              "SAD",
            ),
            Text(
              "pro",
            ),
            Container()
          ],
        ),

